# Does Comvisible-enabled attribute slow down .NET App?

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me to answer whether Comvisible-enabled attribute slows down .NET App?

Comment: Please help me to answer my concern

Answer (score 8):

No- `ComVisibleAttribute` is just an inert attribute until someone looks for it and then performs relevant acts in a context based on the metadata information stored in the custom attribute's serialized form.

Normal execution of a class is not impacted by the presence or absence of the attribute.

An example of something that looks for it is the `regasm.exe` tool - the more items you have marked ComVisible, the more will need to be registered / get registered / will get into the pool of registered stuff (in the Windows Registry in this instance) weighing down your system overall.

Comment: Is calling comvisible-enabled .NET class from VB6 slower than from .NET app to .NET DLL?

Comment: @markattwood: Sorry was OO last 2 days. That's a difficult question to answer quickly. In short, .NET to .NET is going to be a bit quicker as there is no interop layer between them - but you're not talking about orders of magnitude. Having said that, this is very much something that's intended to be fully supported and is in use in a variety of situations for all sorts of systems. But it depends - if you're doing a million iterations of a tight for-loop, it may indeed matter. So, to summarise - in general, there should not be a noticeable issue. But, it depends, and you aint given much context

Comment: You should probably update your answer to include your comment